# Parsing multiple fields of a JSON object and adding to a list using java 8 collections and streams

Tags: java, json, arraylist, collections, java-stream

I make a call to a REST end point, and it returns a JSON object as a `String`. I then parse the `String` to an `Object`.

```
final Object parse = JSONValue.parse(body);
```

I check if the object is an instance of a `JSONArray`, and add selected elements of the object to a list.

```
 if (parse instanceof JSONArray) {
        ((JSONArray) parse).stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(o -> list.add((String) ((JSONObject) o).get("id")));
        ((JSONArray) parse).stream().collect(Collectors.toList()).forEach(o -> list.add((String) ((JSONObject) o).get("uri")));
    }
```

As of now I add all of the `"id"` fields first, and then add all of the `"uri"` fields. In my list I currently have 34 ids followed by 34 uris. I would like to have each id followed by its corresponding uri. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you share the JSON response too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should use `collect`, not `forEach`.

Now, to get each id followed by its corresponding uri, you can use `flatMap`:

```
List<String> list = 
    ((JSONArray) parse).stream()
                       .flatMap(o->Stream.of((String) ((JSONObject) o).get("id"),(String) ((JSONObject) o).get("uri")))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but the code above repeats the id variable twice, so I have 2 id's with no uri.

Comment: @SeanMcGrath That was a typo. Sorry about that. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks again. I should have seen that myself.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested it but this should work.

```
List<Object> result;
if (parse instanceof JSONArray) {
     result = ((JSONArray) parse).stream()
        .flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.get("id"), o.get("uri")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Edit:
Or rather what Eran posted minutes before. He includes proper casts.